# core dump file sometimes not created

Tags: gcc, coredump

I am running Fedora core 14.  I have a program that occasionally (rarely) segfaults.  When this happened most recently I noticed to my consternation that there was no core file generated after the segfault, so I was unable to retroactively gdb the program and core file.

I added an interactive command so that I could intentionally generate a fault that is supposed to generate a core file, and what I found was that sometimes a core file is generated and sometimes it is not generated.  I have set the coredumpsize limit to "unlimited" and have plenty of disk space, and a writeable current working directory.

I would like to debug this issue of not generating core files reliably.  (I'm sure there will be some simple solution, but as of now it eludes me.)

Could someone tell me where to find the source code that generates core dump files when a gcc/g++ program under Linux segfaults or does a floating exception?  I'm hoping that having a look at the source code for how core dump files get generated will help me figure out why I don't get one sometimes.  I am running FC 14, linux kernel 2.6.35.11-83.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Greg Johnson

Answer (score 0):

I always use lxr when I'm trying to track down whats going in the kernel.
exec.c has info in it relating to core dumps.
That may be useful to you.

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/exec.c